# Check values or pattern in one dataframe column against another column to see if match appears

Tags: r, string, match

I have a list of brand name medications that I need to check whether or not they exist in a patients med list.  The patients med list is primarily listed as generic form but I need to check if brand was entered and change it to generic. The patient's med list contains the drug plus directions in the column.  My goal is to create a column that flags if brand shows up either with "yes" "no" or TRUE FALSE.  My dataset contains about 5000 brand name entries and patient list contains about 60000 entries.  I am not sure where to begin because of the difference in patterns from brand list to patient list.  Capitalization is also inconsistent in the patients med list as well.  Any help is appreciated.

Example dataset: MRN is patient ID

```
Brand <- c("Evista", "Rozerem", "Altace")

MRN <- c("121212", "121212", "231212", "432123", "432123", "542345", 
"323412", "242341", "412111", "642321")

MedList <- c("raloxifene 60mg daily", "Rozerem 8mg daily", "evista 60mg 
daily", "metoprolol tartate 25mg twice daily", "ramelteon 8mg daily", 
"ramipril 5mg daily", "omeprazole 20mg daily", "ALTACE 5mg nightly", 
"ramelteon 8mg daily", "imatinib 400mg daily")

Patients <- data.frame(MRN,MedList)
```

My goal is to end up with something like this

```
inlist <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE)

Patients <- cbind(Patients, inlist)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
grepl(paste(toupper(Brand), collapse = '|'), toupper(MedList))
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: I thank you for your help. My example data is not as simple as the real data.   It is throwing an error that I am not sure if related to the commas or the spaces that are in the meds. Multi component meds have commas in the name.   Here is a truncated version of the error.                                               Error in grepl(paste(toupper(dfaDistinct$clean), collapse = "|"), toupper(medList$Med.Description)) : 
  invalid regular expression 'A-METHAPRED|ABACAVIR SULFATE|ABACAVIR SULFATE AND LAMIVUDINE TABLETS|ABACAVIR SULFATE, LAMIVUDINE, AND ZIDOVUDINE|

Comment: You have too many data to put all dfaDistinct$clean in a single grepl (max is around 2.500 elements): you have to split it in several functions. You can refine your grepl to avoid problem related to commas or other special characters, but without an example I can't help you.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it eventually?

Answer (score 1):

If only capitalization but not spelling is an issue, `grepl` should do what you want:

```
grepl(paste0(Brand, collapse = "|"), MedList, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

In case your `pattern` (i.e., "Brand") is a really long vector, you may use `str_detect()` from **stringr**. It is much faster and supports longer patterns (but it has no `ignore.case` argument).

```
stringr::str_detect(tolower(MedList), paste0(tolower(Brand), collapse = "|"))
```